# How to get different background color for different input fields

Tags: html, css, input, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have multiple input fields, how to apply different background-color for alternate fields.
Right now same color is applied to each input field.

Now, Background color for all input field is red, how can I have different color for alternate input fields.

```css
input {

  background-color : red; 

}
```

```html
<table id = "data">

<tbody>

<tr><td><input type="label" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="label" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="label" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="label" /></td></tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by alternate input fields?

Comment: You can add a different class/id for each input. On the CSS side, you set different bg color

Comment: I mean for 1st input field let say background color is red, then for second it should be blue, similarly for 3rd Red , 4th again blue. Same color repeating for alternate input fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for multiple classes. Use the :nth-child() Selector

`#data tr:nth-child(odd) and #data tr:nth-child(even)`

```css
#data tr:nth-child(odd) input {

  background-color : red; 

}

#data tr:nth-child(even) input {

  background-color : blue; 

}
```

```html
<table id = "data">

<tbody>

<tr><td><input type="label" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="label" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="label" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="label" /></td></tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks, It helped, but I don't want to have background-color white each alternate field. What if I want combination of red and blue.

Comment: Answer updated, nth-child(even) and nth-child (odd)

Answer (score 1):

give the input you'd like to be colored in a different color, a class which will override `input {background-color : red;}`:

```css
input {

  background-color : red; 

}

.blue {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<table id = "data">

<tbody>

<tr><td><input type="label" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="label" class="blue"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="label" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="label" class="blue"/></td></tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```